# react-native-video onProgress not working on Android

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-video

I'm currently using `react-native-video": "^5.1.1` on my project.
The `onProgress` event never triggers on my Android Device. It's a Xiaomi Mi 9T (Android v10 and MiUI Global 12.0.5)

I have no clue what could be wrong, I've googled if anyone else was having the same problem and didn't find it. Could it be a device problem?

```
const handleOnProgress = (data) => {
  console.tron.log('on Progress', data)
}

...

<Video
  source={{ uri: convertToProxyURL(additionalInformation?.sourceUrl) }}
  poster={additionalInformation?.thumbnailUrl}
  style={styles.video}
  posterResizeMode="cover"
  resizeMode="cover"
  controls
  paused={paused}
  onLoad={handleOnLoad}
  onPlaybackRateChange={handleVideoChange}
  onProgress={handleOnProgress}
  onSeek={handleSeek}
  onFullscreenPlayerWillPresent={handleFullScreenMode}
  onError={handleOnError}
/>
```

The handle functions are customized to trigger some events.

Comment: I have ran the app on an Android virtual device and I ran into the same problem.

Comment: can you share your code

Comment: Did add the component code

Comment: add handleOnProgress code also

Comment: Added the handleOnProgress

Comment: try `console.log('on Progress', data)` inside `handleOnProgress `

Comment: I tried, but didn't work

Comment: are you using  `const videoPlayer = useRef(null);` and `ref={(ref) => (videoPlayer.current = ref)}`